# Newbie Django Issue

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /genomics/ Reverse for 'pipelinedetail' with
>   arguments '('02152ad7-8399-441c-ba8f-f8871460cd5f',)' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

When I navigate to this URL:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/genoa/

My genoa_urls.py has:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/samples
    url(r'^$', views.samples, name='samples'),
    url(r'^(?P<sequence_id>[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/pipelinedetail/$', views.pipelinedetail,  name='pipelinedetail'),
]
```

The offending line in my template is:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'polls:pipelinedetail' me.sequence_id %}">JSON</a></td>
```

And my view contains:

```
def pipelinedetail(request, sequence_id):
    # sequence_id = '7e6bd861-934f-44be-872a-b59826107bda'
    sample = get_object_or_404(Sample, pk=sequence_id)
    sample_details = sample.values('pipeline_detail')
    context = {'sample_details': sample_details}
    return render(request, 'polls/pipelinedetail.html', context)
```

Here's the top level urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # polls in the url maps to polls.urls.py
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^genoa/', include('polls.genoa_urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that urls.py in a 'polls' app? Show the main urls.py that includes that one.

Comment: Just added additonal info

Comment: `{% url 'polls:pipelinedetail' sequence_id=me.sequence_id %}`

Comment: Just tried that, same error.  With and without the polls: prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Your polls URLs are not in a namespace, so you don't need the prefix.

```
{% url 'pipelinedetail' me.sequence_id %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your suggestions ultimately worked as did my original code once I created a new app and placed my new code there.  Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer, if you want to thank somone, vote up their answer and select (one answer) as the answer. If you want to comment, add a comment.